# Как избавиться от наложения фрагментов после вызова стороннего android-приложения?

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-intent, fragment-manager

Пытаюсь реализовать функцию техподдержки пользователей моего приложения через отправку описания проблемы при помощи стороннего почтового приложения. Ожидается, что оно должно работать так:

1. Во фрагменте "Ещё" есть пункт меню "Поддержка":

[image: Фрагмент "Ещё"]

2. Нажатие этого пункта открывает фрагмент "Поддержка", в котором пользователь проводит описание возникшей у него проблемы с приложением. После чего нажимает кнопку "Отправить":

[image: Фрагмент "Поддержка"]

3. Это приводит к открытию стороннего почтового андроид-приложения при помощи которого пользователь отправляет описание проблемы нам.
4. После отправки письма данное приложение закрывается и происходит возврат в моё приложение к фрагменту "Ещё":

[image: Фрагмент "Ещё"]

Но на последнем шаге происходит какой-то сбой и вместо ожидаемого фрагмента я вижу его с наложенным поверху фрагментом "Поддержка":

[image: Фрагмент "Ещё" с наложенным фрагментом "Поддержка"]

При этом фрагмент "Ещё" находится в фокусе, логи показывают, что прошёл вызов всех методов жизненного цикла фрагмента "Поддержка" до его уничтожения и отключения от активити (onDetach()), а при переходе на любые фрагменты наложение сохраняется:

[image: Фрагмент "Пополнить счёт" с наложенным фрагментом "Поддержка"]

Реализовано это всё следующим образом:

Фрагмент "Ещё" реализован в классе Frag5More.java:

```
public class Frag5More extends MvpAppCompatFragment implements Frag5MoreView {

@InjectPresenter
Frag5MorePresenter mThisPresenter;

@BindView(R.id.lvMore)
ListView lvMain;

private FragmentManager mFm;
private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener lvMainOnItemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {
        FragmentTransaction ftrans = mFm.beginTransaction();
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                ftrans.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
                        .replace(R.id.rlContent, new Frag5MoreAccount())
                        .addToBackStack("Frag5MoreAccount")
                        .commit();
                break;
            case 1:
                ftrans.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
                        .replace(R.id.rlContent, new Frag5MoreHelp())
                        .addToBackStack("Frag5MoreHelp")
                        .commit();
                break;
            case 2:
                ftrans.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
                        .replace(R.id.rlContent, new Frag5MoreSupport())
                        .addToBackStack("Frag5MoreSupport")
                        .commit();
                break;
        }
    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mFm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag5_more, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, rootView);

    if(mThisPresenter.getMenu().size() == 0)
        mThisPresenter.createMenu(getContext());
    MoreListAdapter boxAdapter = new MoreListAdapter(
            getActivity().getBaseContext(),
            mThisPresenter.getMenu());
    lvMain.setAdapter(boxAdapter);
    lvMain.setOnItemClickListener(lvMainOnItemClickListener);
    return rootView;
}
```

Фрагмент "Поддержка реализован в классе Frag5MoreSupport.java:

```
public class Frag5MoreSupport extends MvpAppCompatFragment {

private final static String LOG_TAG = "Frag5MoreSupport";

@BindView(R.id.message)
EditText message;
private FragmentManager mFm;

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Logger.writeString(LOG_TAG, "onCreate");
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    if (getActivity() != null) {
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActivity().setTitle(getString(R.string.more_support));
        ((InputMethodManager) (getActivity()).getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE))
                .toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
    }
    setCurFragContext(getContext());
    this.mFm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Logger.writeString(LOG_TAG, "onCreateView");
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_support, container, false);

    ButterKnife.bind(this, rootView);
    message.requestFocus();

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.tt_menu, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Logger.writeString(LOG_TAG, "onOptionsItemSelected");
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.send:
            String mailto = App.SUPPORT_EMAIL +
                    "?cc=" + "" +
                    "&subject=" + Uri.encode(getString(R.string.app_name)) +
                    "&body=" + Uri.encode(message.getText().toString());
            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
            emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse(mailto));

            try {
                Logger.writeString(LOG_TAG, "startActivity for send e-mail");
                startActivity(emailIntent);
                Logger.writeString(LOG_TAG, "closeActivity after send e-mail");
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ignored) {
                Logger.writeStackTrace(LOG_TAG, ignored.getStackTrace());
                ignored.printStackTrace();
            }

            KeyboardsController.hideKeyboard(getActivity());
            mFm.popBackStackImmediate();
            return true;
        case android.R.id.home:
            mFm.popBackStackImmediate();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

При этом опытным путём установлено, что размещение инструкции

```
                mFm.popBackStackImmediate();
```

хоть до вызова интента, хоть после него, хоть вынос этого вызова в асинктаск --
 никак не влияют на то что получилось.

Как избавиться от наложения фрагментов после вызова стороннего android-приложения?

Comment: видимо разметкам фрагментов (корневому лэйауту) нужно указать какой то непрозрачный фон.

Comment: To @pavlofff: добавил в activity_main.xml для вью в котором помещаются фрагменты указание на фоновый цвет так:

`<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/bottom200">`

Ожидаемого эффекта нет.

Comment: не в активити, а разметки самих фрагментов

Comment: @pavlof Это приводит к "накрытию" фрагментом "Поддержка" всех других фрагментов

Comment: Я пока не нашёл правильного решения. Повесил пока на корневой элемент шаблона разметки "View.GONE" в методе "onDestroyView()". А в методе "onResume()" указал для него "View.VISIBLE".

Comment: Я могу ошибаться, но мне кажется, вместо `startActivity` надо использовать `startActivityForResult`, и соответственно, вызывать `popBackStackImmediate` в `@Override public void onActivityResult`